# Access element within variable element using handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have this code:

[image]

I need to access the `rule_id` element. The problem is that the element inside `auditItems` (in this case `4`) is variable and can be any whole number between `1` and `20`.

For your reference, to access `auditType` element using `each` is `{{#each audits}}{{order.auditType}}{{/each}}`.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you need the `rule_id` for _each_ `auditItem`? Or do you need the `rule_id` for a _specific_ `auditItem`?

Comment: it's for a specific `auditItems` but as I said, it's variable

Comment: How do you know _which_ `auditItem` you need the `rule_id` for? is., How do you know it is the one at `4`?

Comment: you don't, is there a way to check if the `auditItems` number is inside a list? and if so, return the `rule_id`?

Comment: You could write a custom helper. But it is unclear to me what the logic of the helper would be. What if there are multiple items in `auditItems`? Which `rule_id` would the helper return?

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean. Just asume there will be one element inside `auditItems`.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to change the data structure. If `auditItems` only ever has a single key, then changing the object from:

```
auditItems: {
  "4": {
    /* auditItem 4 */
  }
}
```

to:

```
auditItem: {
  /* auditItem 4 */
}
```

would make life easier and more enjoyable.

If, for some reason, this cannot be done, then I think we would need a custom helper to get the first item out of the `auditItems` object and return its `rule_id`. A very simple example of such a helper would be:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getRuleId', function(auditItems) {
  const keys = Object.keys(auditItems || {});
  if (!keys.length) { return null; }
  return auditItems[keys[0]].rule_id;
});
```

This would be called in your template with `{{getRuleId order.auditItems}}`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/6nyzg1or/) for reference.

Comment: @imatiasmb Was this helpful to you?